# Android Deep link: stopped working because some application

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

In the last few days deep link stopped working on my device and the links were opened in another new application that I just installed, after testing I found that the new application includes the following code in manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

and because it's including only **scheme** without any **host**, it's open any link in my device (I disabled chrome browser).

How can I continue open the link in my app, in my case it's youtu.be **host**

Answer (score 0):

i assume you should to put attribute of `host` and `pathPrefix` also if you intent to open link of  `youtu.be` so will be like this:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
        android:host="youtu.be"
        android:pathPrefix="/deep-link"
        android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
```

**Docs**

- [Create Deep Links to App Content](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)
- [Create a deep link for a destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/deep-link#:%7E:text=In%20Android%2C%20a%20deep%20link,deep%20links%3A%20explicit%20and%20implicit.)

Comment: I don't need to destination youtu.be host, and it's working great without **pathPrefix**, until i installed some application that have only `<data android:scheme="https" />`